# Bell numbers in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm writing a program in OCaml which should calculate the first 100 Bell numbers.
Here is my code (I'm using the `Num` module):

```
open Num
let one = num_of_int 1;;
let zero = num_of_int 0;;
```

calculate factorial:

```
let rec factorial n = 
    if n < 2 
    then one
    else (num_of_int n) */ factorial(n-1)
```

calculate Newton:

```
let rec newton n k =
    factorial n // (factorial k */ factorial (n-k))

let bell = Array.make 101 zero;;
bell.(0) <- one;;
bell.(1) <- one;;

let i = ref 2
let k = ref 0
let x = ref zero
let suma = ref zero
let n = ref 100

if !n != 0 || !n != 1 then
    while !i <= !n do   
        while !k <= (!i-1) do
            x := newton (!i-1) !k;
            suma := !suma +/ (!x */ bell.(!k));
            k := !k + 1 
        done;
        bell.(int_of_num !k) <- (!suma);   
        suma:= zero;
        k:=0;
        i:= !i + 1;
    done;;

bell.(int_of_num 20)
```

This is my first program in this language. I have some problems with compiling it.

Comment: I think that your should start from reading some tutorial about syntax, http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/ for instance.

Comment: More concretely, You can rewrite your `while` loops into `for` loops. You always increment integer variable, that's why for loop is what you need.

Comment: Also, you should specify your problem more concretely, for example, by providing error log. Don't forget that `let .. = ..` as toplevel expression doesn't need `in` in the end. But if you use `let` inside another `let` you should cosider adding `in` keywords

Comment: In particular, you miss a `;;` at the end of the last `let n = ref 100`. But it is considered bad style anyway to use global variables as helper variables of an algorithm.

Comment: Without learning ocaml formally, one keeps doing Java thing using ocaml, which is sad

Answer (score 0):

You miss a `;;` at the end of the last `let n = ref 100`. But it is considered bad style anyway to use global variables as helper variables of an algorithm. The code below is a minimal fix of the code from the question and *not* an endorsement of other aspects of bad style, like not using `for` loops mentioned in comments.

```
(* #load "nums.cma";; if in toplevel *)
open Num
let one = num_of_int 1;;
let zero = num_of_int 0;;

let rec factorial n = 
  if n < 2 
  then one
  else (num_of_int n) */ factorial(n-1) 

let rec newton n k =
  factorial n // (factorial k */ factorial (n-k))

let bell input =
  let bell = Array.make (input+1) zero in
  bell.(0) <- one;
  bell.(1) <- one;

  let i = ref 2 in
  let k = ref 0 in
  let x = ref zero in
  let suma = ref zero in
  let n = ref input in

  if !n <> 0 || !n <> 1 then
    while !i <= !n do   
      while !k <= (!i-1) do
        x := newton (!i-1) !k;
        suma := !suma +/ (!x */ bell.(!k));
        k := !k + 1 
      done;
      bell.(!k) <- (!suma);   
      suma:= zero;
      k:=0;
      i:= !i + 1;
    done;

  bell.(input)
```